# Unable to create String[] array inside JSON object angular typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to create below JSON object inside a typescript class

```
private user = {
    username: String,
    password: String,
    roles: String[],
};
```

but angular showing error for key the "roles",
as Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'StringConstructor' . how can  solve this issue

Comment: https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: You should use `:` for specifying the type for variable, `=` is for assigning value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the syntax between assigning a typescript type

```
let variable: String = 'myString';
```

And creating a JavaScript object

```
let object = {
    key: 'value'
}
```

What you're trying to do with the code you posted is create an object with the key "roles" and a value (not a type) of String[].

If you want to make sure your object is using typescript types you can create an interface for it:

```
export interface User {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    roles: string[];
}

...

private user: User = {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    roles: [ 'role1', 'role2' ]
}
```

Comment: "And creating a JSON object" — That's a JavaScript object, not a JSON object.